# Loading DOM into directive on the fly

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, loading

I am building an an single page app. Which requires user to login. On successful authentication the content should be loaded into the same directive as the login form.

In my controller I have a model "activePage" which has the url to template that needs to be loaded.

My directive is "my-page" which is in the homepage. Whenever my model "activePage" (i.e. url) changes I want the "my-Page" directive to load the template on the fly.

I don't want to use routing for this as there is application login involved in change the model "activePage".

```js
angular.module("app",[])
       .controller("main",mainController)
       .directive("myPage",pageDirective);

function mainController()
{
  $scope.url="login.html";
  $scope.submit= submit;
  function submit()
  {
    //authentication stuff goes here and on success the following is set
    $scope.url="home.html";
    //if new user then the url is set to a register page on demand
  }
}

function pageDirective()
{
  return {
      restrict:"E",
      scope: {url:"="},
      templateUrl:scope.url
  };
}
```

```html
<!--index.html-->

<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body ng-controller="main">
    <my-page url="url"></my-page>
    </body>
</html>

<!--login.html-->
  <div><form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email">
    <input type="password" ng-model="password">
    </form>
    </div>

<!--home.html-->
<div>
  <!-- user dasboard is here-->
  </div>
```

Comment: What error you are getting?
I would like to suggest you to add HTML page path in `templateUrl`.
TemplateUrl is specific for HTML page so use Html file in templateUrl

Comment: Thanks -@ojus-kulkarni. I accept that but my application requires the view to be loaded dynamically based on the controller login. That is why my custom directive should be able to read that change and load the recompiled html dom and its directives.

Comment: then use views in router.